# How can I prove the following inequality?

Tags: inequality, products

Let be $N_{n+1}(x)=\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i)$. Now I have to prove that

$$||N_{n+1}(x)||_{\infty,[-5,5]}\leq n!\frac{h^{n+1}}{4},\qquad h:=\frac{5-(-5)}{n}=\frac{10}{n}.$$

I've started with

$$\|N_{n+1}(x)\|_{\infty,[-5,5]}=\max_{x\in[-5,5]}\left|\prod_{i=0}^n(x-x_i) \right|.$$
Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Are the $x_i$ evenly distributed in the interval? Then this looks like a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803875/inequality-of-same-distance-points.